# On what kind of schedule does the US make payments to the WHO?

Tags: united-states, budget, who

I've been wondering whether Trump's cutting of funds to the WHO has had any practical effect on the WHO's budget *so far*. Basically, **how often does the US disburse funds to the WHO? Is it annually, quarterly, monthly, bi-weekly etc.?**

I know there [also](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52817/what-explains-the-large-year-to-year-variation-in-us-voluntary-contributions-to) the "voluntary contributions" to consider, which might complicate the schedule-of-payments question significantly.

I also know that Trump [recently threatened](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/may/19/global-report-trump-threatens-to-pull-out-of-who-over-failed-response-to-pandemic) to make the cuts permanent by withdrawing from the WHO, but that's not what I'm asking here. I want to know if the cuts/freeze so far had a practical effect on the WHO's actual operating funds.

Comment: I'm not sure that payments occur on a regular basis - the US is already [over 41 million dollars behind](https://www.who.int/about/finances-accountability/funding/AC_Status_Report_2020.pdf) on assessed payments from previous years.

Comment: Aside: I was able to find out: the Soviet Union its satellite countries withdrew from the WHO (approximately) between 1949 and 1955 and didn't pay anything during that whole time. Later they paid back some of that money. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5055806/

Answer (score 2):

There is no payment schedule as such - we can see from the US statements of account published by the WHO [here](https://www.who.int/about/finances-accountability/funding/assessed-contributions/en/), and available (for the US) back to 2012, that payments over the last 8 years have been made at fairly random intervals, and never before the payment's due date. The last payments made by the US were in January 2020, roughly a third of which went towards paying off the remainder of their 2018 dues, the remaining amount being put towards paying off their 2019 dues.

The outstanding balance currently for the US sits at a total of around 100 million USD plus 100 million CHF, roughly 40% of which is owed as assessed contributions for their 2019 membership.

The longest gap between two previous payments in the available data was between December 12th 2016 and October 13th 2017, a gap of 305 days. The second-longest was between March 13th 2013 and December 26th 2013, a gap of 295 days. The data is shown in the boxplot below.

[image]

Given that at the time of posting (May 22nd), we are only at 136 days since the US's last payment (indicated by the red dot), this is so far not out of the ordinary for the country, although it is a larger gap than the median.

This is, however, clearly not the international norm. [The UK, for example](https://www.who.int/about/finances-accountability/funding/account_statement/2020/gbr_en_2020.pdf), has made all of its payments in full over the last 4 years, with a clear schedule; usually around 3-4 weeks before the payment is due.